# Unable to install kubernetes

Tags: docker, container

I recently downloaded the kubernetes.tar.gz (version 1.3.3) from their release Page and tried to install kubernetes. But I failed to find the kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/build.sh file after extracting the tar file. 
Can anyone help me out in the installation process please. I am a first timer in using kubernetes.
TIA!

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: You cannot find it because it is not there. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/ubuntu) is the content of the ubuntu folder (no such file, as you can see). Similarly, a quick search [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/find/master) shows all the build.sh files in the distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 15.10. Apparently I had to run the kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/download-release.sh file. This solved the problem for me. Thanks anyways guys!